# Optimización tabla Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

se que esto se sale un poco de la tematica del sitio, espero no se tome a mal.
Tengo una tabla con 90 columnas con la siguiente estructura una pregunta y su observación:

```
   [Documentos]
  ,[ObDocumentos]
  ,[ElementosErgonomia]
  ,[ObElementosErgonomia]
  ,[ComandosAccesorios]
  ,[ObComandosAccesorios]
  ,[Vidrios]
  ,[ObVidrios]
  ,[AceiteMotor]
  ,[ObAceiteMotor]
  ,[AceiteHidraulico]
  ,[ObAceiteHidraulico]
  ,[LiquidoRefrigerante]
  ,[ObLiquidoRefrigerante]
```

Y así hasta completar los 90 campos, en mi concepto me parece que no esta muy bien diseñada de que otra forma se puede optimizar esta tabla?

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: eso solo se va a poder responder conociendo el enunciado o la lógica de negocio que se trata de resolver; pues asi nadamas no sabemos que columnas realmente son necesarias

Comment: Sería bueno conocer el contexto en el que se utiliza la tabla, y la información que almacena. Sin embargo, el hecho de que una tabla tenga 90 campos no indica que no este optimizada, en los cubos por ejemplo es común ver tablas de este tamaño. Tal vez si pones más información podamos ser útiles para ayudar.

Comment: @shadow y Josue Agradeciendo primero sus aportes. La tabla esta vinculada a un formulario web (un cuestionario) en que que se pregunta por x item si cumple o no cumple en caso tal de que no cumpla se llena el campo observación el cuestionario se compone de 45 preguntas con su observacion lo que nos da el total del 90 campos.

Comment: No creo que tu pregunta tenga que ver con _optimización_, sino de modelado. La optimización viene luego de tener el modelo correcto, y en general yo lo hago solo cuando de verdad hay o van a haber problemas de desempeño. Por si las dudas, no [optimices prematuramente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura).

Comment: Si tu pregunta fuera: tener 90 campos es un modelo correcto, entonces la respuesta va a depender del dominio del problema y el alcance de la solución. Es decir, no se puede responder sin saber qué es lo que se trata de resolver y qué se espera de la solución. Quizás puede normalizarse, si, puede ser, pero ¿es correcto y necesario normalizar?, un purista quizás diría que siempre hay que hacerlo. Un ingeniero dirá siempre que depende. Finalmente, si esa fuera la pregunta, creo que sería cerrada por ser demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones, y eso no es compatible con StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El los comentarios te comentan ***¿Cuál es el enunciado?***, o ***¿Cuál es el problema?***. Y tienen razón, según la necesidad es como tienes que diseñar.

Recordemos: Las tablas son objetos, [docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/tables?view=sql-server-2017) explica un poco de ello y varios ejemplos de uso de las mismas.

El problema es, ¿Qué tipo de entidad vas almacenar en ella?. Según lo que puedo apreciar es un tipo de inventario donde tienes la descripción (no sé la verdad que vas almacenar) y su observación (detalles y demás) eso intentas hacer y por esa razón te generará varias campos.

***¿Qué pasaría si un día decides eliminar Vidrios?***, tendrías que modificar la tabla y eso no es recomendado hacerlo a menos que sea una mejora o muy necesario. Entonces, por esa razón el buen diseño te va evitar ese tipo de problemas (acá debes de considerar también el tipo de restricción de los campos y la tabla como tal).

Yo te recomendaría una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
- [id_reg], [id_name], [details], [observations], [state], [active] (los que necesites)
```

Unos registros de ejemplo serían:

```
 - [001], [Documentos], [Documentos de contabilidad], [Ninguna], [Revisión], [1]

 - [002], [Documentos], [Recibos de cuentas por pagar], [Pagar antes del 11 de jun 2018], [Pendiente], [1]
```

Conclusión, aunque tengas una gran cantidad de campos no significa que tu tabla esté mal optimizada el echo de que sea más pequeña no significa mejor. Tienes que pensar en una optimización global con tu Base de datos.

Es mi opinión acerca de ello, espero te sirva un poco y si ves algo más viable comentarlo acá así vemos como lo resolviste.

Suerte.